# Esse código n cria um <li> com o valor especificado na função, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>


            function apresente()

            {
                var newEl = document.createElement('li');
                var newText = document.createTextNode('breno');
                newEl.appendChild(newText);
                var position = document.getElementsByName('ol')[0];
                position.appendChild(newEl);
            }



        </script>

        <form>
            <input type="submit" value = "Enviar" onclick="apresente()"/>
        </form>

        <ol>
            <li></li>
        </ol>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sua tag não deveria estar assim: `<ol name="ol">`? ou então mudar o javascript: `var position = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];`?

Comment: @BrenoRicardo alguma das respostas apresentou a solução para o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois pontos aqui, primeiro o botão é do tipo `submit` que vai executar o envio do formulário, que por não ter um endereço definido para action, causará apenas o refresh da página e "nem executará" o seu JavaScript. Depois o método correto seria  `document.getElementsByTagName()`.

Você pode alterar o tipo do input para `button` ou adicionar um return no seu método caso vá implementar alguma outra regra em que ele deva submeter o formulário em alguma condição.

```js
function apresente()

{
  var newEl = document.createElement('li');
  var newText = document.createTextNode('breno');
  newEl.appendChild(newText);
  var position = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];  
  position.appendChild(newEl);
  
  //não vai submeter o formulário até que seja true;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="return apresente()" />
  </form>
  <ol>    
  </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe algum elemento com o nome `ol` em seu DOM?

Se você quer fazer append em um elemento com a tag `ol` deveria usar `getElementsByTagName`, não `getElementsByName`. Fora queries possivelmente retornando null, não existe nada de errado com o código.

Answer (score 0):

Onde tem:

```
var position = document.getElementsByName('ol')[0];
```

Deveria ser:

```
var position = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
```

Teste [aqui](https://plnkr.co/edit/xUC6wzBsUzW213MxMAh8?p=preview)